# Issues with JtextArea. JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jtextarea

I have a GUI setup with with buttons on them and a `JTextArea`.

I also have an array of Strings with say size of 3.

What I want to do is use an action listener in a way that when the button called "next" is pressed, the `JTextArea` will then show the next cell in the array. The only problem is it displays the array at the same time. I need it to display the next cell when the button is hit

Can anyone help me with the code? Please and thank you.

```
 final ActionListener m2 = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    { 
        arr = new String[3];
        arr[0]= "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";      
        arr[1]= "sssssssssssssssssssssss";
        arr[2]= "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
        text.append(arr[i]);
        }
    }
};

next.addActionListener(m2);
```

Comment: what you have done, share your effort ... the code

Comment: @NeBiPr: [tag:homework] is [slated for burnination](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100/163188).

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I posted what I tried. Any help guys?

Comment: user1681725: @MadProgrammer has already given you the solution (1+ to his answer). What about his answer is confusing? Also, you probably don't want to re-create the array each time the action listener is called. Just create it once elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the basic concept is.  You need a index value to maintain the current index of the array that is being displayed.

From there, each time the user clicks next, you would increment the index and display the next value in the `String`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    currentIndex++;
    // You need to decide what to do when we reach the end of the array...

    String value = myStrings[currentIndex];
    textArea.setText(value);

}
```

Comment: I actually have the textArea displaying the text. my issue is getting it to display the next cell when the button is pressed

Comment: And what do you mean by "next cell"?

Answer (score 4):

To create the button, use the [`JButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) class.  To respond to events, use the `JButton#addActionListener()` method.  If you are having trouble, post what you have tried.  Good luck!